# libgit2sharp not able to commit files only to particular Branch. Help required

Tags: git, git-commit, git-clone, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I have cloned a repo in my local drive. And was able to create branches using libgit2sharp. Below is the code I have used.

```
//Clone
var WorkDir = Repository.Clone(<git-url>, <local-path>);

//Branch create 
var branch = repo.CreateBranch("<branchName>");                     

repo.Branches.Update(branch,
    b => b.Remote = repo.Network.Remotes["origin"].Name,
    b => b.UpstreamBranch = branch.CanonicalName);

repo.Network.Push(branch);
```

The above code works and I am able to see the branches on both local .git folder and the git server.

However, When I try to commit files into the created branch they are not visible in the remote git.

Below is the code.

```
Commands.Stage(repo, <local-clone-path-with-file>);                    
serName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split(new string[] { "\\" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];

// Create the committer's signature and commit
Signature author = new Signature(userName,userName+"@atkinsglobal.com", DateTime.Now);
Signature committer = author;

string comment = timeStamp + "_" + "<BranchName>" + "_" + userName;

//// Commit to the repository
Commit commit = repo.Commit(comment+"_initial", author, committer);

Remote remote = repo.Network.Remotes["origin"];

repo.Network.Push(remote, @"refs/heads/"+<BranchName>, new PushOptions());
```

Please Note: Requirement is that files must be committed to only specified branch, master branch must not have these files.

Answer (score 0):

In the first snippet, you are creating a branch and pushing it.  In the second, you are committing.  Unless you've omitted some code, at no point are you switching to the branch that you created.

```
LibGit2Sharp.Commands.Checkout(repo, branch);
```

Once you've done that, you can commit to it and then push the branch.